# Using pipes to communicate with children in multithreaded programs

Tags: c++, multithreading, posix

I am trying to use fork to execute child programs from a multithreaded parent using code similar to:

```
#include <thread>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <vector>
#include <sys/wait.h>

void printWithCat(const std::string& data) {
    std::vector<char*> commandLine;
    // exec won't change argument so safe cast
    commandLine.push_back(const_cast<char*>("cat"));
    commandLine.push_back(0);

    int pipes[2];
    pipe(pipes);
    // Race condition here
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
        // Redirect pipes[0] to stdin
        close(pipes[1]);
        close(0);
        dup(pipes[0]);
        close(pipes[0]);
        execvp("cat", &commandLine.front());
    }
    else {
        close(pipes[0]);
        write(pipes[1], (void*)(data.data()), data.size());
        close(pipes[1]);
        waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
    }

}

int main()
{
     std::thread t1(printWithCat, "Hello, ");
     std::thread t2(printWithCat, "World!");

     t1.join();
     t2.join();
}
```

This code contains a race condition between the call to pipe and the call to fork. If both threads create pipes and then fork, each child process contains open file descriptors to both pipes and only close one. The result is that a pipe never gets closed and the child process never exits.  I currently wrap the pipe and fork calls in a global lock but this adds an additional synchronisation. Is there a better way?

Comment: Are you sure there's a race condition? pipes is a local variable so each thread will have its own copy.

Comment: pipes is local but the file descriptors opened are global to the process.  A pipe is only closed when all open descriptors are closed and the fork can unwittingly create copies of descriptors you have no knowledge about.

Comment: I see the problem and I don't know better solution. Forking and threads just don't go together well and I've not heard any solution to the mess so far.

Comment: I see... sorry should have read more thoroughly. Is it an option to use a named pipe, that you only open after the fork?

Comment: Closely related: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/12/16/10248328.aspx

Comment: and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/10/18/10457796.aspx and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/07/07/10183884.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think you're avoiding synchronization by avoiding a lock in your code -- the kernel is going to take locks for process creation anyway, probably on a far more global level than your lock.

So go ahead and use a lightweight mutex here.

Your problems are going to arise when different parts of the program make `fork` calls and don't agree on a single mutex (because some are buried in library code, etc)

Comment: For lack of any better ideas I'm going to accept this answer.  Some flavours of Unix have/had a version of spawn which does exactly what I need but it isn't standard.  http://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/sasc/doc700/html/lr2/zid-9275.htm